# Promises in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have problem running multiple premises in series, using Q and reduce idiom (see: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

I tried to follow this example, change it a little bit and here's what I've got:

```
playlist.createPlaylist('playlist')
.then(function(playlistId) {

    songsInfo.reduce(function (accumulatedPremise, songInfo) {
        accumulatedPremise.then(function (response) {
            var def = Q.defer();
            youtube.search(songInfo, function (songInfo, resp) {
                var song = songParser.parse(songInfo, resp);
                if (song !== null) {
                    playlist.addSongToPlaylist(song, playlistId).then(function(response) {
                        def.resolve(response)
                    })
                }
            });
            return def.promise;
        })}, Q());

});
```

Now, I should probably talk a little about main idea behind this:

1) I'm creating a youtube playlist. From createPlaylist function, I'm returning a promise with playlist's ID and then

2) for each SongInfo I have I need to invoke search method on my youtube module. Search function also takes a callback. In this case, I'm invoking addSongToPlaylistMethod if desired song was found/parsed correctly. As you can see, addSongToPlaylist also returns a Promise.

Now, the problem:
all the block inside

```
then
```

method, invoked on 
`accumulatedPremise` 
is executed only once.

You could probably ask me why simply not to use forEach in this case? Well, because of 
http://www.acnenomor.com/3037813p1/playlistitems-batch-insert-youtube-api-v3

Could you please help me fixing it?

Cheers,
Slawek

Comment: Don't look very "promising" (LOLZ intended). Looks like your mixing the callback hell inside a promise then function? Since promises are designed to prevent callback hell, use promises instead of the nested callbacks. Q has provisions for this with it's `nfcall()` function.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't nfcall deprecated? Shouldn't I use ninvoke instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the reduce function.

```
accumulatedPremise.then(function (response) {
```

should be:

```
return accumulatedPremise.then(function (response) {
```

Comment: Yeah, this Was as simple as that... That feeling when you're staring at the code for an hour and miss something like that... Thanks!